# Model error everytime I submit form to create user (MVC Identity)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm new to this and building a form to create a new user but no matter what I get a model error whenever I submit the form:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+d__16`2[System.Web.Mvc.ModelState,System.Web.Mvc.ModelError]
```

Can anyone see where i'm going wrong?

View

```
@model PGS.Models.ViewModels.CreateUserViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Main_Template.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create User</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))

{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, "User Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, "First Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, "Surname", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserGroup, "User Group", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserGroup, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserGroup, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create User" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Model

```
public class CreateUserViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Surname")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User Group")]
    public string UserGroup { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[ActionName("Create")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(ApplicationDbContext DbContext, CreateUserViewModel model)
    {

        IEnumerable<ModelError> errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            IdentityResult ir;
            var rm = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(DbContext));

            var um = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(DbContext));
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email, FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName, UserGroup = model.UserGroup };

            ir = um.Create(user, model.Password);

            if (ir.Succeeded == false)
            {
                return View(model);
            }
            else
            {
                ir = um.AddToRole(user.Id, "pxpuser");
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        }

        Response.Write(errors);

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Paste the whole stack trace for your exception

Comment: I don't get one, it wasn't giving any error, the form submits but doesn't add the user which is why I added `IEnumerable<ModelError> errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);` to see what was going on, which only gives me a general `ModelError`

Comment: `ModelError` contains a propery `ErrorMessage`, what is the value of this property?  This will reveal what the model error is.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

I set a breakpoint on line:

```
if (ir.Succeeded == false)
```

and it showed me in Visual Studio:

```
"User name ********* is invalid, can only contain letters or digits."
```